# Why doesn't this collision detection apply to objects previously created?

Tags: python, pygame, collision

After hours of searching, I still can't figure out why only the most recently spawned circle is affected by the collision detection. I commented out the code in question. I experimented with sprites and that may be the answer but I still got the same results.

```
import pygame,random
pygame.init()
width,height,radius = 1280,720,20
class Ball(): 
    def __init__(self):  
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.vx = 0
        self.vy = 0  
def make_ball():
    ball = Ball()
    ball.x = random.randrange(radius, width - radius)
    ball.y = random.randrange(radius, 100)
    ball.vx = random.randint(1,2)
    ball.vy = 0
    return ball
def main():
    rect_x = 60    
    display = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("BOUNCE")
    running = True
    ball_list = []
    ball = make_ball()
    ball_list.append(ball)
    while running:  
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    ball = make_ball()
                    ball_list.append(ball)
        for ball in ball_list: 
            ball.x += ball.vx
            ball.vy += 0.02
            ball.y += ball.vy
            if ball.y >= height - radius:
                ball.vy *= -1
            if ball.x >= width - radius or ball.x <= radius:
                ball.vx *= -1    
        display.fill((0,0,0))   
        for ball in ball_list:
            random_color = (random.randint(1,255),random.randint(1,255),random.randint(1,255))
            circle = pygame.draw.circle(display,random_color,(int(ball.x), int(ball.y)),radius)   
        rectangle = pygame.draw.rect(display,(255,255,255),(int(rect_x),660,60,60)) 
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and rect_x > 0:
                rect_x -= 2
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and rect_x < width - 60:
                rect_x += 2
        '''if pygame.Rect(circle).colliderect(rectangle) == True:   ###THIS IS THE BAD CODE!
            print('Your Score:',pygame.time.get_ticks())
            running = False'''
        text = pygame.font.Font(None,120).render(str(pygame.time.get_ticks()),True,(255,255,255))
        display.blit(text,(50,50)) 
        pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.quit()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I copied it over but some of the indentation doesn't seem correct and since I am not familiar with your code, i can't presume to know how to fix the indentation. please sort that out so folks can have a simple copy paste.

Comment: Thanks The4thIceman, I just fixed it so it should be good to copy now.

Comment: I am not sure i understand what the issue is

Comment: The issue I'm having has to do with collision detection between any circle and the square you play as. If you remove the quotation marks in the code, my intent is that when a circle touches the square, the game ends. The problem is that a collision is only detected for the last circle spawned in. I hope that clears things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indentation and code organization is the key to this. the offending section is (comments removed):

```
for ball in ball_list:
    random_color = (random.randint(1,255),random.randint(1,255),random.randint(1,255))
    circle = pygame.draw.circle(display,random_color,(int(ball.x), int(ball.y)),radius)   
rectangle = pygame.draw.rect(display,(255,255,255),(int(rect_x),660,60,60)) 
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and rect_x > 0:
        rect_x -= 2
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and rect_x < width - 60:
        rect_x += 2
if pygame.Rect(circle).colliderect(rectangle) == True:
    print('Your Score:',pygame.time.get_ticks())
    running = False
```

You had all the correct pieces, but the order in which you are doing them is off as well as the indentation:

```
    for ball in ball_list:
        random_color = (random.randint(1,255),random.randint(1,255),random.randint(1,255))
        circle = pygame.draw.circle(display,random_color,(int(ball.x), int(ball.y)),radius)
        rectangle = pygame.draw.rect(display,(255,255,255),(int(rect_x),660,60,60))
        if pygame.Rect(circle).colliderect(rectangle):
            print('Your Score:',pygame.time.get_ticks())
            running = False
```

This will now run through every ball in the list and check each one for collision. notice the colliderect if statement is indented into the for loop. Also notice i removed the KEYDOWN check from in the middle of it all

Speaking of that I would recommend using:

```
pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT] and rect_x > 0:
    rect_x -= 2
if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT] and rect_x < width - 60:
    rect_x += 2

for ball in ball_list:
    # for loop from above
```

instead of what you had. This works best for when you want to allow for holding a key down. pygame.key.get_pressed() gets the state of all the keys all the time, not just when an event happens